# How to multiselect duplicate values using select2 library

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I am select using select2-multiple function, and here is my code

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose Colors" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Red">Red</option>
 <option value="Green">Green</option>
 <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
 <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

I want the user can add Orange value multiple times if he wants. By default select2 multiple didnot accepts duplicate value. Can someone here please help

Comment: can you explain use-case. Particularly if both options have same value how will you (or someone) will know what triggers what. If your case is just to count, add a counter like feature with selection option, which would be better by design.

Comment: Hi, i am not seeing that behaviour have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cgLous35/)

Answer (score 1):

You can select both if you hold the shift key by clicking on the option.
Maybe you should do Orange-1 and Orange-2 as Value. So if you want to submit it in a form you have two different GET or POST parameter.

Check this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

```html
<select data-placeholder="Choose Colors" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Red">Red</option>
 <option value="Green">Green</option>
 <option value="Orange-1">Orange</option>
 <option value="Orange-2">Orange</option>
</select>
```